# Apache mod_proxy and reverse configuration.

Tags: apache, grails, server

My application is running on http://www.jobAtFinger.com:8080/myProjectName/ and i want to make it accessible only by domain name without port number and myProjectName.

I have done my grails project setup according to http://grails.asia/step-by-step-tutorial-on-how-to-host-your-grails-application

This tutorial didn't installed apache.Do i have to install it to resolve this problem.

I read may articles but was not able to do it correctly.But it came up with setting mod_proxy and its reverse for apache.

How to do it.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really grails related, since you are talking about running the final product a `war` file in tomcat and having apache acting as a front end to your application.

You obviously didn't do much research before posting the question meaning you probably desire to be spoon fed.

Upon googling modproxy tomcat apache the first result was:

http://blog.marcnuri.com/running-apache-tomcat-and-apache-httpd-on-port-80-simultaneously/

To expand on my answer, mod_proxy will reverse tunnel port 8080 traffic to port 80. You could also look into a slightly older technology known as mod_jk.

Currently using mod_proxy but maybe looking to switch back to mod_jk since with mod_jk it is easy to custom tune multiple instances of tomcat and have it work round/robin as well as easier to be able to upgrade application across two nodes with minimal downtime aka no downtime due to one being active/inactive during process. Possibly impacting current users  experience.

The choice is yours but I would suggest you research topics like this before posting a question, it usually means looking at more than 1 site !